# Synonyms: [anagrams] and [permutations]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed we have both [anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagrams) and [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations). Is there any reason not to make [anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagrams) a synonym of [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)? If so, how should the tags be used?

Comment: I'd say [anagrams] is a sub-tag of [permutations], but they're close enough  that I don't see any reason not to merge them.

Comment: @Challenger5 in what sense is it a subtag?

Comment: The set of anagrams does not contain the original string, but the set of permutations does.

Comment: also anagrams refers specifically to strings, while permutations applies to any multivalue data type

Comment: @DestructibleLemon That's a fair point, but you could always tag the challenge [tag:string] [tag:permutations].

Comment: (but I don't think you would tag list anagrams)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagrams) should be made a synonym of [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations), and we should additionally add [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) on a case-by-case basis

Presently, many [anagram](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagram) challenges are [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) already. Of those that aren't, they don't necessarily feel particularly string-focused (e.g. "write a program that outputs an anagram of itself" is not really [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) because "write a quine" is also not really [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)). Additionally, some [anagram](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagram) challenges have five tags more relevant than [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) already.

EDIT: I've done the additions of [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string); almost all the challenges that needed it had it already, and I tagged the few remaining challenges over the last several days (to avoid spamming the active list).

I've now proposed the tag synonym. If you have 1250 reputation and a score of 5 or more on [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations), you can vote for it [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/permutations/synonyms). Note that even if the other answer gets consensus rather than this one, we'll still have a record of which question was originally in which tag, so we'll still be able to implement it, and I haven't seen anyone argue for keeping the two tags entirely separate, thus the general concept of synonymising them seems to have consensus.

Comment: I've approved the synonym and merged the tags (i.e. automatically retagged all [anagrams] challenges to [permutations]).

Answer (score 4):

### [anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagrams) should be turned into [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)

This is because an anagram is a particular type of permutation: a permutation of a string.

Comment: I just looked into the feasability of this. There are plenty of challenges which are [tag:anagrams] but not [tag:string]. Many of them already have five tags, thus making the retag in question impossible. (Typically speaking, challenges which are [tag:anagrams] but not [tag:string] are asking for an anagram of a *program*; does that count as [tag:string]?)